# Obtaining a special formula for the Theta-Beta-M diagram

Tags: shock-waves

I'm currently studying shockwaves, particularly their effects on drag.
I've stumbled upon an odd formula in "Elements of Gasdynamics" (Liepman and Roshko, pages 52-53), in there I saw an alternative formula for the theta-beta-mach diagram, and the author committed a passage in which I've been having problems replicating.

Starting from:
$
\frac{\tan (\beta - \theta )}{\tan(\beta)} = \frac {(\gamma-1) M_1^2 \sin^2(\beta)+2}{(\gamma+1)M_1^2\sin^2(\beta)}
$

He divides and multiplies right hand side by $\frac{1}{2} M_1^2 \sin^2(\beta)$

To obtain:
$\frac{1}{M_1^2 \sin^2(\beta) } = \frac{\gamma+1}{2}\frac{tan(\beta-\theta)}{\tan{\beta}}-\frac{\gamma-1}{2}$

Finally he ends up with: $M_1^2 \sin^2(\beta) -1 = \frac{\gamma+1}{2} M_1^2 \frac{\sin(\beta)\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\beta-\theta)}$

The last passage is not very clear and I have no idea how he ended up with that, I've tried with Wolfram and both equations are solved for the same* points, yet I am unable to find a way to obtain the latter.
**My main question** is if there is other literature where this formula appears, I liked it because it allows the introduction to linearized supersonic pretty easily rather than using the potential.
Needless to say I tried all the trigonometric tricks I could find.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

PS: I consulted, Fundaments of AD, Elements of Aerodynamics of Supersonic Flows, aerodynamics for engineering students and Dyamics and Thermodynamics of compressible flows.

Comment: I pulled out my original edition of Liepmann and Roshko (c. 1957, 1965 printing) and found the equations above on pp. 87-88. Getting the second equation is easy enough, but I am stumped also on getting the 3rd.